# Must a woman cover her hair in bed when she is a niddah?

Tags: marriage, tznius-modesty, hair-covering, niddah

Must a woman cover her hair in bed when she is a niddah? I assume it is standard for a married woman who is a niddah to carry the rules of tzniut into the bedroom; that is, to wear modest sleepwear, etc. But does she also need to keep her hair covered in her bedroom/all night? Does this practice vary by community?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78322/1516

Comment: I've never heard of it, but both me and my wife are certain there are people who would say yes, you have to.  I recommend any answers that explain the answer in both directions.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/74143/759

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The opinion of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein ([YD Vol. II: 75](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_919_139.pdf#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH)) -- which I've heard quoted by several prominent American Ashkenazi authorities on Laws of Nida -- is that the "modesty" required of a woman in her own home, when she's a nida, is not the full set that would apply for going out in public (e.g. hair covering). Rather, it's whatever she would normally feel comfortable wearing inside when it's just her family around. (I presume when she's not a Nida, her kids don't see her walking around naked -- but very likely they might see her in pajamas.) Hence in virtually all cases, hair covering in the house wouldn't be required. (Yes if you want to be extra pious and holy and stuff ... but as Rabbi Feinstein warned elsewhere, don't be extra holy and pious at the expense of straining your marriage.)

Comment: "Hence in virtually all cases, hair covering in the house wouldn't be required." This doesn't follow from what you said earlier. I think in many, if not most, Orthodox homes, the mother does not go around the house in front of her kids with her hair uncovered. Therefore, according to you, it would actually NOT be permissible for her to do so when a Nidah...

Comment: @Shraga I suppose we have different perspectives here. I would think that in many if not most Orthodox homes the mother does in fact go around the house with uncovered hair. Your logic is correct, it's just a question of empirically what's out there.

Comment: Its not a matter of perspective, its a matter of where you live as per @Shaloms answer from R' Moshe, "it's whatever she would normally feel comfortable wearing inside " whatever she normally wears and as far as I know (i.e. where I live) most woman cover their hair inside their house... (do you think they have a snood hanging by the door for when someone knocks....?)

Comment: @Shalom why  is covering hair "straining your marriage"?

Comment: @R.Mo Chazal felt it was important that a man see that his wife looks pleasant, regardless of the phase of month. Depending on the couple and the situation, he might be fine seeing her in a snood 24x7, but he may prefer to see her real hair when there are no visitors. That's a question for a local rabbi. Rav Moshe's quote was about a woman who wants to shave her head altogether.

Comment: @Shalom Does R'Moshe explicitly include hair covering in this? I ask because hair covering is not necessarily [only] a part of tznius per se

Comment: @SAH even if hair covering is an objective requirement irrespective of tznius, that's in public, not in your own home.

Comment: @Shalom Just suggesting that invoking R'Moshe's discussion of tznius only helps if hair covering is an inyan under that banner.

Answer (score 2):

I remember that I read in "Darkei Tahara" of Rav Mordechai Elyahu Zatsa"l that is a h'oumra and even for people who do that, it's not necessary to put again the kissouy roch if it falls during the night.

Sorry but I don't know the Ashkenazi point of view.