# Hilchos niddah and hair

Tags: niddah, hair-covering

In regards to Niddah, does a woman need to cover her hair in her husbands presence (when she's a niddah)? Also would the answer be based on wether you hold a married woman's hair is ervah or tznius (daas moshe or dass yehudit)?

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: regarding your first question, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14625/759